# initdata: No memory for kernel buffers

Tags: sql-server, linux, sql-server-2019

I recently upgraded my SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition on RedHat Enterprise Linux 7.6 to SQL Server 2019 CTP 3.0.

The mssql-server service will no longer start.  /var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog shows the following:

> 2019-06-12 09:36:31.98 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (CTP3.0) - 15.0.1600.8 (X64)
>           May 17 2019 00:56:19
>           Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
>           Developer Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) 
>   2019-06-12 09:36:32.04 Server      UTC adjustment: -5:00
>   2019-06-12 09:36:32.05 Server      (c) Microsoft Corporation.
>   2019-06-12 09:36:32.07 Server      All rights reserved.
>   2019-06-12 09:36:32.08 Server      Server process ID is 32.
>   2019-06-12 09:36:32.09 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file '/var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog'.
>   2019-06-12 09:36:32.10 Server      Registry startup parameters:
>            -d /var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf
>            -l /var/opt/mssql/data/mastlog.ldf
>            -e /var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog
>   2019-06-12 09:36:32.15 Server      Command Line Startup Parameters:
>            --accept-eula
>   2019-06-12 09:36:32.18 Server      SQL Server detected 1 sockets with 4 cores per socket and 4 logical processors per socket, 4 total logical processors; using 4 logical processors based on SQL Server licensing. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
>   2019-06-12 09:36:32.20 Server      SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
>   2019-06-12 09:36:32.23 Server      Detected 7856 MB of RAM. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
>   2019-06-12 09:36:32.24 Server      Using conventional memory in the memory manager.
>   2019-06-12 09:36:32.28 Server      Buffer pool extension is not supported on Linux platform.
>   2019-06-12 09:36:32.29 Server      Error: 17128, Severity: 16, State: 1.
>   2019-06-12 09:36:32.29 Server      initdata: No memory for kernel buffers.

/var/opt/mssql/mssql.conf contents:

> [sqlagent]
>   enabled = false

`systemctl status mssql-server` shows:

> mssql-server.service - Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine
>      Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
>      Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Mon 2019-06-17 13:57:45 CDT; 26min ago
>        Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux
>     Process: 71357 ExecStart=/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>    Main PID: 71357 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>       Tasks: 0
>      CGroup: /system.slice/mssql-server.service
>
> Jun 17 13:57:45 rhel72-sqlserver.localdomain systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
>   Jun 17 13:57:45 rhel72-sqlserver.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit mssql-server.service entered failed state.
>   Jun 17 13:57:45 rhel72-sqlserver.localdomain systemd[1]: mssql-server.service failed.
>   Jun 17 13:57:45 rhel72-sqlserver.localdomain systemd[1]: mssql-server.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
>   Jun 17 13:57:45 rhel72-sqlserver.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine.
>   Jun 17 13:57:45 rhel72-sqlserver.localdomain systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for mssql-server.service
>   Jun 17 13:57:45 rhel72-sqlserver.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine.
>   Jun 17 13:57:45 rhel72-sqlserver.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit mssql-server.service entered failed state.
>   Jun 17 13:57:45 rhel72-sqlserver.localdomain systemd[1]: mssql-server.service failed.

I've tried `yum remove mssql-server`, followed by `yum install mssql-server`, but no change.

Any ideas?

Attempting to run the `mssql-conf setup` executable, as root, results in this:

> [root@rhel72-sqlserver bin]# sudo ./mssql-conf setup
>   usermod: no changes
>   Choose an edition of SQL Server:
>    1) Evaluation (free, no production use rights, 180-day limit)
>    2) Developer (free, no production use rights)
>    3) Express (free)
>    4) Web (PAID)
>    5) Standard (PAID)
>    6) Enterprise (PAID) - CPU Core utilization restricted to 20 physical/40 hyperthreaded
>    7) Enterprise Core (PAID) - CPU Core utilization up to Operating System Maximum
>    8) I bought a license through a retail sales channel and have a product key to enter.
>
> Details about editions can be found at
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=852748&clcid=0x409
>
> Use of PAID editions of this software requires separate licensing through a
>   Microsoft Volume Licensing program.
>   By choosing a PAID edition, you are verifying that you have the appropriate
>   number of licenses in place to install and run this software.
>
> Enter your edition(1-8): 2
>   The license terms for this product can be found in
>   /usr/share/doc/mssql-server or downloaded from:
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=855862&clcid=0x409
>
> The privacy statement can be viewed at:
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=853010&clcid=0x409
>
> Enter the SQL Server system administrator password:
>   Confirm the SQL Server system administrator password:
>   Configuring SQL Server...
>
> This is an evaluation version.  There are [153] days left in the evaluation period.
>   This program has encountered a fatal error and cannot continue running at Mon Jun 17 14:35:43 2019
>   The following diagnostic information is available:
>
> ```
>   Reason: 0x00000007  
>   Status: 0xc0000218  
>  Message: Cannot open or read the persistent registry: \SystemRoot\security.hiv.
> ```
>
> Stack Trace:
>                 000000006bd347d0
>                 000000006bd31af7
>                 000000006bd31d3a
>                 000000006bd30ea5
>                 000000006bd2faf7
>                 000000006bd73371
>        Process: 75209 - sqlservr
>         Thread: 75213 (application thread 0x4)
>    Instance Id: ffcf27f9-18a5-485a-8a9d-34482c5efe06
>       Crash Id: cb1238f4-2504-457c-bbb3-d7ecad750aec
>    Build stamp: fbef7d3acfbedcf62a42c8909366dbba3852b92cabb497c2169680835fd60276
>   Distribution: Red Hat Enterprise Linux
>     Processors: 4
>   Total Memory: 16637898752 bytes
>      Timestamp: Mon Jun 17 14:35:43 2019
>
> Red Hat Enterprise Linux
>   Capturing core dump and information to /var/opt/mssql/log...
>   Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
>        Users in the 'systemd-journal' group can see all messages. Pass -q to
>        turn off this notice.
>   No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions.
>   Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
>        Users in the 'systemd-journal' group can see all messages. Pass -q to
>        turn off this notice.
>   No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions.
>   /usr/bin/tail: cannot open ‘/var/log/messages’ for reading: Permission denied
>   Attempting to capture a dump with paldumper
>   Captured a dump with paldumper
>   /usr/bin/find: ‘/usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d’: Permission denied
>   /usr/bin/find: ‘/usr/libexec/initscripts/legacy-actions/auditd’: Permission denied
>   Core dump and information are being compressed in the background. When
>   complete, they can be found in the following location:
>    /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.06_17_2019_14_35_43.75209.tbz2
>   Initial setup of Microsoft SQL Server failed. Please consult the ERRORLOG
>   in /var/opt/mssql/log for more information.
>   [root@rhel72-sqlserver bin]#

I'm logged into the server as `root`, so I don't understand why I'm seeing "access denied" errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, being the smarty-pants I am, I thought it would be easier to just login to my RHEL system *as root*, then I wouldn't need to `sudo` every time.

Turns out that was a mistake.

I was able to fix my install by logging in using my "normal" Linux account, then run sudo commands per the docs to remove and re-install SQL Server binaries from the Microsoft repo.  I also needed to run the following commands to reset ownership and group-membership for filesystem objects for my existing /var/opt/mssql/* folders:

```
chown -R mssql /var/opt/mssql/*
chgrp -R mssql /var/opt/mssql/*
```

Moral of the story, don't shoot yourself in the foot.  It hurts.  Oh well, I guess I've got another small chapter for my book:

> Adventures in Linux, AKA, It's NEVER going to be the year of Linux on the desktop.